# Seo friendly urls with the Zend Router

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-controller-router

I want to create seo friendly urls in my Zend Framework application but how is the correct syntax for this:

```
$newsroute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
   'news/:action/:id_:title',
    array( 'controller' => 'news' ));
```

:id_:title obviously doesn't work since Zend didn't know that _ is a separator? Do i need to use the regex router for this or does it work with the normal one too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed a regex route would do the thing.

If for any reason you don't want to use the regex route, there is a simple workaround via a front controller plugin:

```
//replace the :id and :title params with a single one, mapping them both
$newsroute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        'news/:action/:article',
         array( 'controller' => 'news' )
   );

// in a front controller plugin, you extract the Id form the article param
function function dispatchLoopStartup( Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request ) {

    if( $request->getParam( 'article', false ) ){

        $slug = $request->getParam( 'article' );
        $parts = array();
        preg_match( '/^(\d+)/', $slug, $parts );

        // add the extracted id to the request as if there where an :id param
        $request->setParam( 'id', $parts[0] );
    } 
}
```

Of course you can also extract the title the same way if you need it.

Don't forget to build your 'article' param when you want to generate urls:

```
 $this->url( array( 'article' => $id.'_'.$title ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid dealing with the links contain special characters, you can use this plugin for Zend Framework.

https://github.com/btlagutoli/CharConvert

```
$filter2 = new Zag_Filter_CharConvert(array(
               'onlyAlnum' => true,
               'replaceWhiteSpace' => '-'
           ));
echo $filter2->filter('éééé ááááá ? 90 :');//eeee-aaaaa-90
```

this can help you deal with strings in other languages